# WPF container with fix size children

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, grid, containers

I want a `container` that have 3 columns and in each column, the cell can wrap it's content like the picture below

[image]

So far, I've done this:

```
    <ListBox Name="listQuestion">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

But the result is every cell have the same size as the biggest cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a grid with three separate lists as their columns you should be able to use a combination of a Grid and a listbox

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="0"/>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="1"/>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

A grid will give you the most flexibility in your layout and allows you to have elements span multiple columns or rows. If you don't need all that flexibility you could use a stackpanel instead

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizonal">
    <ListBox/>
    <ListBox/>
    <ListBox/>
</StackPanel>
```